# Replace array elements with map

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays:

```
@a = [ 
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
@b = [a, b, c]
```

I need to replace n-th column in `a` with `b` like:

```
swap_column(0)
#=> [a, 2, 3]
    [b, 5, 6]
    [c, 8, 9]
```

(This is for using [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) for solving equations system, if anybody wonders.)

The code I've come up with:

```
  def swap_column(n)
    @a.map.with_index { |row, j| row[n] = @b[j] }
  end
```

How do I get rid of assignment here so that `map` returns the modified matrix while leaving @a intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wanted is `dup`. Also, you had the return value of the `map.with_index` block wrong.

```
def swap_column(i)
  @a.map.with_index{|row, j| row = row.dup; row[i] = @b[j]; row}
end
```

or

```
def swap_column(i)
  @a.map.with_index{|row, j| row.dup.tap{|row| row[i] = @b[j]}}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by sawa is good and the main point is you need to `dup` your inner arrays for this to work properly. The only reason for this additional post is to point out that often when you are using with_index so that you can directly 1:1 index into another array you can simplify the code by using `zip`.

```
def swap_column(n)
  @a.zip(@b).map {|r,e| r.dup.tap{|r| r[n] = e}}
end
```

What `zip` does is combine your two arrays into a new array where each element is an array made of the two corresponding elements of the initial arrays. In this case it would be an array of an array and an element you want to later use for replacement. We then map over those results and automatically destructure each element into the two pieces. We then `dup` the array piece and `tap` it to replace the nth element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transpose` to do the following:

```
class M
  attr :a, :b

  def initialize
    @a = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]
        ]
    @b = [:a, :b, :c]
  end

  def swap_column(n)
    t = @a.transpose
    t[0] = @b
    t.transpose
  end

end

m = M.new
=> #<M:0x007ffdc2952e38 @a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], @b=[:a, :b, :c]>
m.swap_column(0)
=> [[:a, 2, 3], [:b, 5, 6], [:c, 8, 9]]
m  # m is unchanged
=> #<M:0x007ffdc2952e38 @a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], @b=[:a, :b, :c]>
```

Comment: Isn't `transpose` an overkill? Two of them here, actually. I heard it can be quite slow on large arrays.